# Tmux keybindings don't work in VSCode integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmux

When I use tmux in VSCode's integrated terminal, for some reason none of the keybindings work to create new panels, split screens etc. The VSCode bindings override this and things change in the editor instead of the terminal, despite the terminal being focused. Any solution to this? Asked Chatgpt but didn't get a useful answer.

My tmux.conf:

```
set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"
set -sg escape-time 0
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-x
bind-key C-x send-prefix
bind-key Left select-pane -L
bind-key Right select-pane -R
bind-key Up select-pane -U
bind-key Down select-pane -D
set -g history-limit 10000
```

[image]

Comment: Okay so I managed to get a temporary fix by just deleting all VSCode keybinds that use Ctrl + X (remapped default Ctrl + B), now it works as expected